# Problema con la caché al hacer llamada recursiva

Tags: java, spring

Intento explicar , tengo un método que funciona correctamente pero tengo un problema con la caché.

Cuando ejecuto la petición por primera vez funciona correctamente , pero cuando llamo al método otra vez sigue con los mismos valore , entonces no se que pasa que siempre me carga lo mismo uno y otra vez.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<URL>>getURL() throws Exception {
        List<URL> urls = urlService.getAllArticles();
        if (null == urls || urls.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(NO_CONTENT);
        }else{

            for(int i=0;i<urls.size();i++){
                if(urls.get(i).isHasOpen()==false){
                    getAllUrls(urls.get(i).getUrl());
                    urls.clear();
                    this.getURL();
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(urls);
                }

            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(NO_CONTENT);
        }
    }
```

Necesitaría que urls se inicializara , pero no se si hay alguna opción de hacerlo mejor.

Comment: Prueba inicializar el objeto que envias al web services cuando termine la llamada exitosa

Comment: no entiendo la logica de ese ciclo `for` tal parece que siempre ese metodo retorna `NO_CONTENT` o una lista vacia. Como sabes que la respuesta esta cacheada? El browser te indica que la respuesta esta cacheada? o el servicio tiene configurado un cache?

Comment: La lógica del for dice que mientras no hayan urls que hayan sido abiertas se ejecute un Selenium , cacheada no se si es correcto , lo que pasa es que cada vez que llamo al propio método me carga los mismos valores no los cambios @Klaimmore

Comment: @RaulCacacho , puedes ponerme un ejemplo de lo que me dices no entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: No se cual es la consecuencia de ejecutar los métodos de los servicios, pero si haces `urls.clear();` y luego `return ResponseEntity.ok(urls);` no hay de otra que lo que retorna es una lista vacía.

Comment: Vale ya lo he solucionado , he creado un rest template y vuelvo a lanzar la petición.